# How to search and replace in a Clojure script data structure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I would like to have a search and replace on the values only inside data structures:

```
(def str [1 2 3 
              {:a 1 
               :b 2 
               1  3}])
```

and

```
(subst  str  1  2)
```

to return

```
[2 2 3 {:a 2, :b 2, 1 3}]
```

Another example:

```
(def str2  {[1 2 3] x, {a 1 b 2} y} )
```

and

```
(subst  str2  1  2)
```

to return

```
{[1 2 3] x, {a 1 b 2} y}
```

Since the 1's are keys in a map they are not replaced

Comment: The restriction that only values and not map keys should be replaced means you'll likely be rolling your own.

Comment: In `{[1 2 3] x, {a 1 b 2} y}`, the both `1`s are values inside  keys. Are you saying that values only are naked values or naked values inside values?

Comment: Function in my answer seems to work just like you've described. I wonder if it works for you and if not, what's the problem with it?

Comment: I meant only naked value, not values in keys

Comment: @Zubair, try it for yourself, that's the way it works (second solution).

Comment: Yes, it is does. Sorry, my mistake. Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is using of [`postwalk-replace`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.walk/postwalk-replace):

```
user> (def foo [1 2 3 
              {:a 1 
               :b 2 
               1  3}])
;; => #'user/foo
user> (postwalk-replace {1 2} foo)
;; => [2 2 3 {2 3, :b 2, :a 2}]
```

Although, this method has a downside: it replaces all elements in a structure, not only values. This may be not what you want.

---

Maybe this will do the trick...

```
(defn my-replace [smap s]
  (letfn [(trns [s]
            (map (fn [x]
                   (if (coll? x)
                       (my-replace smap x)
                       (or (smap x) x)))
                 s))]
    (if (map? s)
      (zipmap (keys s) (trns (vals s)))
      (trns s))))
```

Works with lists, vectors and maps:

```
user> (my-replace {1 2} foo)
;; => (2 2 3 {:a 2, :b 2, 1 3})
```

...Seems to work on arbitrary nested structures too:

```
user> (my-replace {1 2} [1 2 3 {:a [1 1 1] :b [3 2 1] 1 1}])
;; => (2 2 3 {:a (2 2 2), :b (3 2 2) 1 2})
```

Comment: OP only wants to replace values. There is also a `1` key that should not be replaced.

Comment: @A.Webb, Good point! I'll see if I can come up with something more relevant.

Comment: "Only values" is not super well defined. What about an input like `{[1 2 3] x, {a 1 b 2} y}`? Here the first `1` is not a key, but it is a value inside of a key. And the second `1` is the value in a map, but that map is the key of another map. Are these being replaced? In your edited solution, no. But either way it's pretty weird; I recommend that OP think about whether there's an important reason for map keys to be left untouched.